# wordpress get user registered date in pure php,returns 1970-01-01

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am trying to get user registered date in php file,always return 1970-01-01?(I need date format like as:2016-06-14)

What I know is php need to include wordpress themes first,then get user info

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<?php
$reg_date=date("Y-m-d ", strtotime($registered));
echo $reg_date;
?>
```

I think it might need codes to connect current user,

```
get_currentuserinfo();
...
```

So any one know how to get it?

Comment: When you just `echo $registered` what does it output? It may already be in timestamp format.

Comment: ...or rather, where does `$registered` come from...?

Answer (score 0):

Really old question, but if someone finds this error like me. Be sure that your string format date is not an empty string.

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("")) == "1970-01-01"
```